# This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.31

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the latest Android Studio and I'm able to build and run my app fine with `compose_version` set to `1.0.5`. However, I'd like to use the latest stable compose version `1.1.1`.

I try to simply update the project `build.gradle` so it contains the following pointing to the desired compose version and the corresponding compatible kotlin version. These values are referenced in the app's `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    }
```

And in Android Studio, I go to Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates and download the latest Kotlin plugin (Early Access).

If I open Tools > Kotlin > Kotlin REPL, I see `Welcome to Kotlin version 1.7.0-RC2-release-258 (JRE 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)`.

Now, I try to Rebuild Project.

I get the error:
`This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.31 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck but don't say I didn't warn you!).`

I don't wish to `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` given the warning, but I even tried that option and got other build errors.

Why is Kotlin version 1.5.31 being used? Shouldn't updating the Kotlin plugin have gotten Android Studio to switch to a more recent Kotlin version (as suggested by the Kotlin REPL message)? How can I make it such that Kotlin 1.6.10 is used and I stop getting the error?

Comment: run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see where 1.5.31 dependency comes from. Also [this guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html) can be helpful - look for `resolutionStrategy`

Comment: Check the `buildscript` dependency `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:x.x.xx"`

Answer (score 49):

Got the same error when using Compose `1.1.1.` and Kotlin `1.7.0`.

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires
> Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.7.0
> which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

Changed the below block in my **build.gradle (app module)**

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.2.0
}
```

This is my plugins block in build.gradle (project):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

This Android developers page helped with picking the compatible versions :-

[Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Don't forget to sync and rebuild.

Comment: this should mark as the answer!

Comment: It worked. I got an error for kotlin version 1.9.10. Updated the kotlin plugin in build.gradle(project):     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false

Answer (score 20):

Compose uses the kotlin compiler defined in your `buildscript` block:

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
   //....
   dependencies {
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}
```

If you are using the `plugins` block in `settings.gradle` or `build.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {

    plugins {
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' 
    }
}
```

Comment: Updating the `buildscript` block in the app's build.gradle seemed to do the trick. However, the change to the `plugins` block caused build errors. I ended up using `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10'  apply false` in the `plugins` block.

Comment: @blu if you are using the buildscript block, you don't need to use the plugins block

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things you need to ensure are in sync(compatible with the other) for kotlin to work properly.

1)compose_ui_version='1.2.1' of buildscript in build.gradle(project)

2)plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' in build.gradle(project)

3)kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.1' in composeOptions in build.gradle(app)

To get the latest version of compose compiler and its corresponding kotlin version check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler?gclid=Cj0KCQjwkOqZBhDNARIsAACsbfJ-gwm9EEG_S7fyNRC6QCv9RllloD3_TssX8mTi8YD2GdYfC3HagNoaAhKEEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#kts).

Answer (score 2):

you should update your compose compiler
from `build.gardle.app` make it "kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion" last version of compose compiler

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 'last version'
}
```

you can see lastest update from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler

and make sure you use last version of kotlin also

Answer (score 2):

You MUST use the correct version mapping:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Using this help me.

`build.gradle (:app)`

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0-beta03"
}
```

Comment: But this is not a stable release.

Comment: Also need to set org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21

Answer (score 1):

for me what I had to edit is to locate build graddle(Project):

1. first load [compose_version](https://www.jetpackcomposeversion.com/) to see the latest stable compose_version.
2. 

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        //2. change here to the latest stable (compose_version) that you got in step 1
        compose_version = '1.3.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       //when you run you app, The next error will tell you the version of Kotlin that the latest compose_version needs, edit as below to the version required in the error
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I updated my dependencies versions.

in `build.gradle (Project)`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.4.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

in `bui.gradle ( :app)`:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> buildscript {
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
>     }
> }
>
> plugins {
>     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
> }
> ```

and build.gradle(Module)

> ```
> composeOptions {
>     kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
KOTLIN_VERSION = "1.7.20
```

use

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in project level gradle file, i changed

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false` to

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0'`

it works for me.

Answer (score -5):

1. Go to your project level build.gradle file
2. There in the plugin section below mentioned 2 libraries has to be in the same version to remove this error:

> {
>
> ```
> ...
>
> id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
>
> id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10' apply false
> ```
>
> }

3. If required, change:

> compileSdk 33

&

> targetSdk to 33

. (inside app level build.gradle file).

4. Now sync the project & reload the priview. It will work fine.