# "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1." error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a dictionary application with kotlin and I was planning to use the room database to keep the words, but after writing my codes, this error keeps popping up.

**EDIT ERROR**

```
Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.0/51736992f422993a1e741051bdf3c12801bc1ca1/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.0/a5f42c684ad9003160ef0d0f693ecf0ba7b13549/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/721eb3f536dfebc7923ca73bc7386d87/transformed/room-runtime-2.4.3-api.jar!/META-INF/room-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fc43dbac19dd2a5bd7a61cadd61fc30e/transformed/room-ktx-2.4.3-api.jar!/META-INF/room-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
C:\Users\enest\AndroidStudioProjects\DictionaryApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\enestigli\dictionaryapp\data\locale\OwnDicDatabase.java:7: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class OwnDicDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType, kapt.kotlin.generated]'

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.0/baf82c475e9372c25407f3d132439e4aa803b8b8/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.0/da6bdc87391322974a43ccc00a25536ae74dad51/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.0/a5f42c684ad9003160ef0d0f693ecf0ba7b13549/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.0.jar (version 1.7)
    C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.0/51736992f422993a1e741051bdf3c12801bc1ca1/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.0.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.0/51736992f422993a1e741051bdf3c12801bc1ca1/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.0/a5f42c684ad9003160ef0d0f693ecf0ba7b13549/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/enest/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/721eb3f536dfebc7923ca73bc7386d87/transformed/room-runtime-2.4.3-api.jar!/META-INF/room-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

it continues with errors similar to this, I only shared a certain part of it so that it is not too long

there was a solution about searching the solution for this on the internet and changing the application kotlin version but it didn't work

**EDIT : build.gradle(Project.DictionaryApp)**

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-alpha02'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' apply false
    //hilt
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version "1.5.21" apply false

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(Module.DictionaryApp.app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enestigli.dictionaryapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"



    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0"

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
    //implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.1'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"

    //Material theme3
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha12"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.0-alpha12"

    //skrape{it}
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'

    //compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"



}
```

**NOTE**

**These errors happened while trying to use the room. I wasn't getting such an error before**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537582/this-version-1-1-1-of-the-compose-compiler-requires-kotlin-version-1-6-10-but)

Comment: You are using incompatible versions of **Kotlin** and **Compose**. [Compatibility map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#kts)

Comment: unfortunately neither is my solution because I am using the right version and I tried that solution on the internet.

Comment: No, you are not. You are using `compose_version = '1.0.1'` which requires Kotlin version of `1.5.1`. If you are using Kotlin `1.7.1` you should be using `compose_version = '1.3.1'`.

Comment: Because you changed the Kotlin version after the build, there may have been a bug with the Kapt version, have you tried Clean and Rebuild the project? It is also recommended that you inform the Kapt version to avoid this type of problem, just add the following line in the project's build.gradle: `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version "$SameAsKotlin" apply false`

Comment: I did what you said, but I'm getting the same error, it's probably because of this error because this error keeps popping up, how can I solve it?                                                                                              
Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:

Comment: and this error keeps popping up:                                                                                                kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1. 
I think if I can find and fix the cause of these two errors, the problem will be solved.

Comment: The error message is very straightforward about version incompatibility, if you already changed the versions and did the clean/rebuild but even so the problem continued, the situation seems very strange to me. What you can do now is update your question with the exact code you have in both `build.gradle` files, and then we check if you really did it the right way.

Comment: I think so too. i changed my codes with new changes i made

Comment: You have a lot of libraries that are very outdated and others with newer versions, this difference is definitely causing the problem. Ideally, you should update all libraries, not downgrade to old versions, for example, after reproducing your error here, using the versions you are using, I tried to reduce the Room version (because you said that the problem happened when adding it) until it worked, but nothing changed, so the problem may not be Room, as well as Room and another library together, so it is difficult to identify. But updating everything, it will work perfectly.

Comment: I solved the problem, but it was happening for some reason that I don't know, and it worked when I opened and closed the project again. Here is the master of Android studio. I hope I will not encounter such an error from now on.